# Send and Sync question for futures::stream::unfold

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

Rather new to Rust outside of tiny pet projects. I want to process some data and am currently consuming data from Redis but need to exchange data with other services right after. So I decided to define

```rust
#[async_trait]
pub trait Protocol {
    async fn send(&self, value: &str) -> Result<()>;
    async fn subscribe(&self) -> Result<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String>>>>;
}
```

with an implementation for a Redis transport (using fred 5.2.0) like this:

```rust
async fn subscribe(&self) -> Result<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String>>>> {
    let c = self.client.clone();
    let key = self.input_key.clone();
    let s = stream::unfold((c, key), |(c, key)| async move {
        loop {
            let value = match c.blpop::<(String, String), _>(&key, 2.0).await {
                Ok((_, value)) => value,
                _ => { continue; }
            };

            return Some((value, (c, key)));
        }
    });
    Ok(Box::pin(s))
}
```

That works, until I try to `tokio::spawn` a task to handle these messages.

So I can do this:

```rust
pub async fn run(&self) {
    let protocol = self.protocol.clone();
    let s = protocol.subscribe().await.unwrap();
    s.for_each(|x| async move {
        println!("Received {}", x);
    }).await;
}
```

As soon as I try to run this as a task I run into all sorts of Send/Sync related issues and feel lost. Any pointer would be appreciated

```rust
pub async fn run(&self) {
    let protocol = self.protocol.clone();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let s = protocol.subscribe().await.unwrap();
        s.for_each(|x| async move {
            println!("Received {}", x);
        }).await
    });
}
```

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/foo.rs:24:22
    |
24  |           tokio::spawn(async move {
    |  ______________________^
25  | |             let s = protocol.subscribe().await.unwrap();
26  | |             s.for_each(|x| async move {
27  | |                 println!("Received {}", x);
28  | |             }).await
29  | |         });
    | |_________^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn futures::Stream<Item = std::string::String>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/foo.rs:28:15
    |
25  |             let s = protocol.subscribe().await.unwrap();
    |                 - has type `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = std::string::String>>>` which is not `Send`
...
28  |             }).await
    |               ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `s` maybe used later
29  |         });
    |         - `s` is later dropped here
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /home/bam/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.26.0/src/task/spawn.rs:163:21
    |
163 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
```

Comment: Why do you need an `async fn` if it's returning a stream?

Comment: Also: you don't need to `clone()`, just return `Result<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String> 
+ '_>>>`. Also, please create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

Just mark the returned `Stream` as `Send`:

```rust
async fn subscribe(&self) -> Result<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = String> + Send>>>;
```